# Wordpress widget/plugin not showing Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I have some problems with a plugin for wordpress that refuses to show up on Chrome & IE. On Firefox is working perfectly.
I had the same issue with the facebook like box but I manage to fix with deleting chrome cache and cookies.
I tried disabling `text-rendering` but without succes.
I use Sahifa theme if anyone else use it.
Link: `https://www.southparkromania.com`

The Social Login widget is on the right sidebar bellow `CONECTEAZA-TE CU:`.

Thanks.

Comment: your widget is showing on chrome.

Comment: http://oi43.tinypic.com/k2n89.jpgthis is what I get on my pc and other 2 devices

Comment: check the source code with developers tool in chrome.

Comment: I checked it like ten times but everything is fine in my opinion.